# Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
jQuery('img').each( function($) {
    var mySrc = $(this).attr( "src" );
    $(this).before( '<a href="' + mySrc + '" class="link">' );
    $(this).after( '</a>' );
});
</script>
```

Hello,

I can´t make this code work, and I don´t know why... I am trying to add a link to every image of my site, and it is located just before the

I am really bad with Javascript/Jquery so please any help/feedback would be really appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
jQuery(function($){
    $('img').each( function() {
        var mySrc = $(this).attr( "src" );
        $(this).wrap( '<a href="'+mySrc+'" class="link"></a>' );
    });
})
</script>
```